# virtualenvwrapper on Ubuntu 10.10 - Python

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

can't get virtualenvwrapper to work on Ubuntu 10.10 desktop.

> mkvirtualenv test_env

returns:

> ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your path

---

I followed the install instructions to the letter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, is virtualev installed in the same python as virtualenvwrapper? It requires installing virtualenv separately.

Answer (score 3):

I got that same message when installing virtualenvwrapper using the MacPorts package manager  (version py27-virtualenvwrapper @3.2_0). I had virtualenv installed, also via MacPorts. The only way I could get it to work was adding the bash environmental:

`export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=virtualenv-2.7`

to my .profile file. Not at all Ubuntu 10.10, but if you've got a working `virtualenv` on your set-up, maybe virtualenvwrapper needs a pointer ...